# Subscribing to Consul Key-Value

Tags: web-services, docker, consul

I'm trying to use Consul's [Key-Value API](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/kv.html) to pass a JSON configuration to an app running in one of my containers. It works great, but the API does not provide any pub-sub functionality (just read/write/delete) for a key.

So far, I managed to artificially compensate by using the [Watch feature](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/watch.html) to restart the container whenever the key changes, but that leaves me with the need to

1. Externally configure Consul (either load a new configuration, or use the CLI, to specify a key to watch, and a shell script to run)
2. Restart my app in mid-run - a good way to potentially lose data.

Is there any programatic way (other than polling every x seconds) to get notified of a key change in Consul, or should I just back away from this solution, and move to Redis?

Comment: Hello, I try to do a pub-sub functionality with Consul. I've read your question and I would like to know your feedback, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look at consul's sources, it seems that the "watch" is a simple periodic pull. You could implement something similar in your code to achieve this.

Periodic run of the watcher: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/watch/plan.go#L46

KeyWatch Handler: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/watch/funcs.go#L29

Comment: Thanks. I can implement a periodic pull directly against the key using the existing API. I'm just wondering if there's something else I'm missing. It seems like there should be an API endpoint for change notification. Or is that a new feature I need to request?

Answer (score 0):

Consul offers the server side watch feature, as you have noted, however that requires server side configuration and a subsequent restart. You can implement it client side by long polling the KV tree. Note that Consul will return the entire tree when any of the keys or values within the root have changed. The following open issue claims to give the ability to only return specific elements of the sub tree that have been modified - which would greatly reduce load and increase performance in the case of watching a KV path that has many items: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/6366 - perhaps one day the Consul team will get round to implementing it for the KV store.

When implementing a client side Consul KV watch, it's important to adhere to Consul's recommendations for blocking calls specified here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/api-docs/features/blocking

You can use the KV get API with a specific index and recurse=True to achieve this. Here's some example Python code.

Note this does not implement the rate limitng feature recommended by Consul. Can easily use anyio's CapacityLimiter for implementing this: https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/synchronization.html#capacity-limiters

The below code requires installing packages: `aiohttp` and `py-consul`

```
import asyncio
import consul.aio
from typing import Tuple


async def poll_consul_kv_path_callback(
    client: consul.aio.Consul, path: str, current_index: int
) -> Tuple[bool, int]:
    # the index checks and rate limiting functionalities are made following Consul's recommendation here:
    # https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/api-docs/features/blocking
    new_index = await _poll_path_by_index(client, path, current_index)
    update_occurred = True
    if new_index <= 0:
        print(f"invalid consul index {new_index} on {client} {path}")
        current_index = 0
    if new_index < current_index:
        # expect to see this due to items in the watched KV path with the highest index being removed.
        print(
            f"consul index reset on poll of {client} {path} from index {current_index} to {new_index}"
        )
        current_index = 0
    elif new_index == current_index:
        print(
            f"poll of {client} {path} returned with no change in index {current_index}"
        )
        update_occurred = False
    else:
        current_index = new_index
        # there's been an update to the watched path
        print(f"update to watched path has occurred")
    return update_occurred, current_index


async def _poll_path_by_index(client: consul.aio.Consul, path: str, index: int) -> int:
    """
    specify an index for the path. If the index matches the max current ModifyIndex within the path, then the below
    call to get will wait until the path has been updated, causing the index to be incremented and the API call to
    return. This allows users of this API to 'watch' a path.
    """
    print(f"polling path {path} with consul client {client} with index {index}")
    try:
        # the consul api requires trailing '/'. For example, polling 'foo/bar' will actually poll 'foo/'
        index_ret, _ = await client.kv.get(
            path + "/",
            separator="/",
            recurse=True,
            index=index,
            wait="30s",
        )
    except TimeoutError as ex:
        print(f"timed out waiting for poll on {client} {path} at index {index}: {ex}")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(
            f"unexpected error occurred polling {client} on {path} at index {index}: {ex}"
        )
    else:
        index = int(index_ret)
    return index


async def main():
    consul_host = "your-consul-hostname"
    consul_kv_path_to_watch = "kv/path/to/watch"
    client = consul.aio.Consul(host=consul_host)
    current_index = 1
    while True:
        # todo must implement a rate limiter here to ensure the frequency of polls to the Consul server are rate limited
        # if frequent updates occur
        update_occurred, current_index = await poll_consul_kv_path_callback(
            client, consul_kv_path_to_watch, current_index
        )
        if update_occurred:
            print("do your work on a consul update here")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```